# react toggling checkall button in Redux Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

Currently I am learning Redux and the problem I have now is that the selectall checkbox, should be working when someone hit this button. Result is that all the checkbox should be toggling (check or uncheck). But now I am stuck with my logic. When someone call the selectAll function, it should iterate through all the input checkboxes and from that point it should check or uncheck all the checkboxes.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { selectAll } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const CheckAll = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            TodoList <input type="checkbox" onChange={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                selectAll()
                }}/>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        selectAll: () => dispatch({type: 'SELECT_ALL'})
    }
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(CheckAll);

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { removeTodo } from '../actions';

const TodoList = ({ todos, removeTodo }) => {
    return (
        <div>
             {todos.map((todo) => {
                return (
                    <li key={todo.id}>
                        // checkbox should be toggling here when somene clicks on the selectAll checkbox. 
                        <input type="checkbox" checkbox="false"/> 
                        {todo.text}
                        <span onClick={e => removeTodo(todo.id, 1)}>x</span>
                    </li>
                )
            } )}
         
        </div>
    )
}

const mapDispatchProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        removeTodo: id => dispatch(removeTodo(id))
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        todos: state.reducer || []
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchProps)(TodoList);

// the reducer below

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [
                ...state, 
                {
                    id: action.id,
                    text: action.payload,
                    completed: action.completed
                }
            ];
        case 'REMOVE_TODO':
            return state.filter(({id}) => id !== action.id);
        case 'SELECT_ALL':
            console.log('');
            const allMarked = state.every(action => action.completed);
           
            return state.map(todo => ({
                ...todo,
                completed: !allMarked
            }));
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

I want a functional checkbox, that when everyone clicks on that checkbox, it should be toggling checked or unchecked. But keep in mind that if the user clicks on the individual checkbox, it should not affect the check/uncheckall button.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your checkboxes are not [controlled inputs](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+controlled+input&oq=react+controlled+input&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2743j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). You're looking at the the `completed` property to see if the boxes have been checked, but their values are not linked to that property and are not updating the state when they change.  You'll need to feed that value to the inputs as its `checked` property and add an `onChange` handler to keep it current:

```
             {todos.map((todo, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={todo.id}>
                        // checkbox should be toggling here when somene clicks on the selectAll checkbox. 
                        <input type="checkbox" checked={todo.completed} onChange={() => checkTodo(index)}/> 
                        {todo.text}
                        <span onClick={e => removeTodo(todo.id, 1)}>x</span>
                    </li>
                )
            } )}
```

And for a handler you'll need to add a new action and reducer case:

```
case 'CHECK_TODO':
            const copy = Array.from(state);
            copy[action.index].completed = !copy[action.index].completed;
            return copy;
            break;
```

You'll of course need to add the index to the action, or use the ID if you'd like, and map its dispatch.  Also as [Junius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858806/junius-l) pointed out, be sure you are referring to your props correctly, but I don't think you need `this` for a functional component, and maybe I've just never seen it before but I don't think a JSX component will render without brackets:

```
const CheckAll = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TodoList/> <input type="checkbox" onChange={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            props.selectAll()
      }}/>
   </div>
  )
}
```